# How can I connect to a container from a different pod in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I create two containers in two pods in k8s, `elasticsearch` and `kibana`.
`kibana` container needs to access elasticsearch endpoint on the port 9200. So I set the env to be `http://es-cluster-1.elasticsearch.default.svc.local:9200` based on this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/.

But in kibana logs I can see it can't reach to this endpoint. What did I do wrong?

`{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-31T07:44:05Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6,"message":"[ConnectionError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200"}`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              value: single-node
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          image: kibana:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5601
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    name: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 5601
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your YAML config, but it doesn't work, the pod keep restarting

[like @Dom said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65517865/7166519), your service should be available at "elasticsearch-entrypoint.svc.cluster.local", only iff your pod is running

For more regarding DNS, read the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id

That being said, lets fix your YAML config,

now that your pod is not running, what should we do? Check the logs and so did I and I found interesting log entry:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
```

So, there must be something wrong with elasticsearch discovery service, ok.
Luckily I found this blog by rancher labs https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-11-22-deploying-elasticsearch/ about running elasticserach on k8s, I read their config and tweak your original config to become

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: es-config
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    network.host: "0.0.0.0"
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: es-cluster-0
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
    xpack.security.enabled: false
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: elasticsearch
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: elasticsearch-config
        configMap:
          name: es-config
          items:
            - key: elasticsearch.yml
              path: elasticsearch.yml
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
          volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-config
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
            subPath: elasticsearch.yml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          image: kibana:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5601
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    name: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 5601
```

The difference is that now the ES pod read config from our specified config map, to make sure the service is running properly we specify livenessProbe in our YAML spec or manually using

```
/ > dig +search elasticsearch-entrypoint

; <<>> DiG 9.16.6 <<>> +search elasticsearch-entrypoint
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27045
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: ca540a28cfb103a8 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.244.82.52

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.96.0.10#53(10.96.0.10)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 31 09:33:32 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 157

/ #
/ > nc -vz elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local. 9200
elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local. (10.244.82.52:9200) open
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your configure but still got this error: `Request error, retrying\nGET http://elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200/_xpack => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200` 

For the restarting issue, there is one env is missing from the yaml file and I have updated it in the post. Could you try with the config file again?

Comment: Whoops, I pasted wrong config, I just edited my answer, could you retry the configuration?
I added this additional entry to ES config from the previous:

```
  cluster.initial_master_nodes: es-cluster-0
  xpack.security.enabled: false
  xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

Comment: I tried your latest config but still got this error: `GET http://elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200/_xpack => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200"`

Comment: do you restart(by killing the pod) the pod after you apply the configuration?

Comment: yes, I did `kubectl delete -f es.yml` and run `kubectl create -f es.yml`. BTW, I am running inside minikube.

Comment: I copy-pasted my the config from my answer (without discovery.type: single-node) apply it to my KIND cluster and it works, I also tried to put `discovery.type: single-node` ans it also works fine. I haven't try minikube in a while, AFAIK it doesn't seem to different from KIND, but clearly this is DNS problem. where did you get the error message, is it from kibana?
what about changing the ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS value to `http://elasticsearch-entrypoint:9200` does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes the log is from kibana. I got the log by running `kubectl logs -f kibana-64b99fb8dd-2slfp` command.  I tried to use `http://elasticsearch-entrypoint:9200` but got the same error. I also login to kibana pod and I can't ping these endpoints.

Comment: I think you have minikube related problem here, I think you might be interested in this github issue https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2575#issuecomment-430252377

Comment: I start minikube by `minikube start` without the parameter `--vm-driver=none`. Is the issue related?

Comment: Why do you think the endpoint is `elasticsearch-entrypoint.svc.cluster.local` without the `default` domain name and the StatefulSet cluster name prefix?

Comment: Why do you think "elasticsearch-entrypoint.svc.cluster.local" would work? you do need the namespace.

so for you service,it's either elasticsearch-entrypoint, elasticsearch-entrypoint.default, elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc, or entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local, check your container `/etc/resolv.conf` and `man resolv.conf` to know why it works like that.

Here's a link to the docs regarding k8s dns https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Based on this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/, the hostname should start with a prefix like `es-cluent-0`. It seems it conflicts with the dns pod service doc.

Comment: "the hostname should start with a prefix like es-cluent-0" - True, you can confirm this by `cat /etc/hostname` inside the container, the FQDN is es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local. "It seems it conflicts with the dns pod service doc" - is it? how do you confirm this? I don't think this is the main issue with your cluster, but let know. by the way, are you able to resolve another service in your cluster?

Comment: No, I am still not able to fix this.

Comment: Ok, finally it works after I restart minikube. Thanks mate.

Comment: My question about the hostname is that why it works without the prefix? I assume it should be `es-cluster.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local` rather than `elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Like I said before, you should take a look at your container `/etc/resolv.conf` file and `man resolv.conf` to know more about the DNS resolution. I'll give you a brief answer, there's this feature called `search` and `options` with `ndots:n` parameter in resolv.conf file which read by your c to resolve dns address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it via the service created so traffic is balanced between all pods in the statefulset
`elasticsearch-entrypoint.svc.cluster.local` (if your cluster DNS is the default, cluster.local)
You also don't need to specify the namespace unless you're trying to communicate out of the same namespace (if kibana and elasticsearch pods both in default)

This service will use the label selector to send traffic to any pods with the labels name: elasticsearch

Comment: I have tried to use `elasticsearch-entrypoint.svc.cluster.local` hostname but still not able to reach it.

Comment: and why the endpoint you mentioned looks different than the one in this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Answer (score 0):

While reproducing the issue I have encountered exact same problem with kibana pod unable to connect but the reason for that was  `es-cluster-0` pod was falling with this error:

```
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

This is because elasticsearch uses a  [`mmapfs`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html#mmapfs) driectory by default to store its indices.  The default operating system limits on mmap counts is likely to be too low, which may result in out of memory exceptions.

This value can be changed with this command:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To do this you have to exec into `minikube`:

```
minikube ssh
```

And then use that command:

```
docker@minikube:~$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

You can read more about vm-max-map count [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html).